# DIFFERENCE BETWEN = AND == IN IF CONDITION

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
  int i = 1, n;
  printf("enter value of n");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  for (i = 1; i <= n; i ++) {
    printf("%d", i);
    if (i = 5)
      break;
  }
}
```

WHY OUTPUT OF MY CODE IS 1 WHICH IS NOT DEPENDENT ON VALUE OF N(INPUT)?

Comment: WHY ARE YOU SHOUTING!? DID YOU PRESS THE CAPS LOCK KEY BY ACCIDENT?

Comment: BECAUSE `if (i=5)` ASSIGNS THE VALUE `5` TO `i`, WHICH EVALUATES TO TRUE BECAUSE IT'S NONZERO AND HENCE BREAKS OUT OF THE LOOP.

Comment: THE COMPARISON OPERATOR `==` LOOKS LIKE A PAIR OF EARPLUGS. NOT SURE WHY I THOUGHT OF THAT, JUST HAPPENED TO CROSS MY MIND.

Comment: Ahahaha, this caps gag is amazing. OH WAIT! AMAZING!!!

Comment: The difference is the same as in any other expression. What did your basic C text book tell about those operators?

Comment: I apologize for not shouting.

Answer (score 11):

The `=` operator sets the value of the lvalue (in your case, `i`) to the expression on the right hand side, and then returns the new value of the variable. This means `i=5` sets i to 5, and then returns 5, which is always true as `5 != 0`. Therefore you program immediately exits after the first number is printed, which is `1`.

Comment: Maybe his problem is that C is case-sensitive?

Answer (score 3):

That will always equate to true, since = is actually setting the value, not testing for equality. Use == to test for equality.

Answer (score 2):

`==` will check if both values are equal. `=` will act as an assignment. Hence 
`i=5` will always be true and the loop will `break`.

Comment: Speak up, I can't hear you.